# "No ad config" message when loading rewarded ads in admob in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I have been working on a project and want to implement admob ads in it. I followed official documentation and implement banner, interstitial and rewarded ads as well.

Everything works fine in editor, but when testing on real device, only banner and interstitial works. Rewarded ads don't show up. When i check android logcat, this message pop up:

`Load error string: { "Code": 3, "Message": "No ad config.", "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads", "Cause": "null", "Response Info": { "Response ID": "null", "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "", "Adapter Responses": [] } }`

And "AdFailedToLoad" callback fires.

Then i created a fresh project and implemented everything i just did, everything works fine on the same real device. All three types of ads shows up.

I am really confused. I don't want lose my original project progress. Did my project broke?
Please help me.

P.S.: I am using test ad units in all cases.

Comment: Kindly have a look at [Ad Load Errors](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/ad-load-errors) article to modify `AdFailedToLoad` and then check as suggested.

Comment: Already did that. That's why it is showing the above shown message in logcat.